# C++ , Cannot receive data and invalid socket after one accept

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I write a POSIX-BSD Socket [Listener-Client] and i have a problem with it.I think that i have a fault in my code but i cannot realize where is the fault.My OS is Windows 10 64Bit.I create a listener with EServer class on localhost , and i try to connect to this listener by ESocket.After connect , i can send data from ESocket to server socket , but i can't receive it in server socket.And also , Next incoming connections will have a INVALID_SOCKET Error.Here is my code:

```cpp
----------------EServer.h-----------------

#ifndef ESERVER_H
#define ESERVER_H


#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <ESocket.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN32
  #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
  #endif
  #include <winsock2.h>
  #include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#else
typedef int SOCKET;
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
#endif


class EServer
{
    public:
        EServer(int port);
        virtual ~EServer();
        int Destruct();
        int Close();
        bool isListening();
        ESocket AcceptClient();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // ESERVER_H




----------------EServer.cpp-----------------

#include "EServer.h"
#include "stdio.h"



SOCKET sx = NULL;

EServer::EServer(int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    //Create a socket
    if((sx = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) < 0)
    {
        sx = NULL;
        return;
    }



    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( port );

    //Bind
    if( bind(sx ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        sx = NULL;
        return;
    }

    printf("Listening status: %i\r\n",listen(sx,100));
}

EServer::~EServer()
{
    Destruct();
}


bool EServer::isListening()
{
    return (sx != NULL);
}


ESocket EServer::AcceptClient()
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    SOCKET new_socket;

    #ifdef _WIN32
    int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(sx , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Invalid");
    }
  #else
     socklen_t c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(sx , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
    if (new_socket < 0)
    {
    }
  #endif


    return ESocket(new_socket);
}

int EServer::Destruct()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    return WSACleanup();
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}



int EServer::Close()
{


  int status = 0;
  #ifdef _WIN32
    status = shutdown(sx, SD_BOTH);
    if (status == 0) { status = closesocket(sx); }
  #else
    status = shutdown(sx, SHUT_RDWR);
    if (status == 0) { status = close(sx); }
  #endif

  return status;

}


---------------ESocket.h-------------------


#ifndef ESOCKET_H
#define ESOCKET_H

#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN32
  #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
  #endif
  #include <winsock2.h>
#else
typedef int SOCKET;
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
#endif

class ESocket
{
    public:
        ESocket(string ip,int port);
        ESocket(SOCKET e);
        virtual ~ESocket();
        int Destruct();
        int Close();
        int setAsNonBlock();
        bool SendData(string data);
        bool isConnected();

        string ReceiveData(int len);

static int Init()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsa_data);
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}

    static string getIP(char* host)
    {

    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;

    char ip[100];


    int i;

    if ( (he = gethostbyname( host ) ) == NULL)
    {
        return "";
    }

    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;

    for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++)
    {

        strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
    }
    string x = ip;
    return x;
    }


    protected:

    private:

};

#endif // ESOCKET_H






--------------------ESocket.cpp---------------

#include "ESocket.h"
#include "stdio.h"

SOCKET s = NULL;


ESocket::ESocket(string ip,int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) < 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
    }
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( port );
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
    }
}

ESocket::ESocket(SOCKET e)
{
    s = e;
}

ESocket::~ESocket()
{
    Destruct();
}



bool ESocket::isConnected()
{
    return (s != NULL);
}



int ESocket::Destruct()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    return WSACleanup();
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}



int ESocket::Close()
{


  int status = 0;
  #ifdef _WIN32
    status = shutdown(s, SD_BOTH);
    if (status == 0) { status = closesocket(s); }
  #else
    status = shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR);
    if (status == 0) { status = close(s); }
  #endif

  s = NULL;
  return status;

}


bool ESocket::SendData(string data)
{

    if( send(s , data.c_str() , data.length() , 0) < 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


string ESocket::ReceiveData(int len)
{
    int recv_size;
    char reply[len];
    if((recv_size = recv(s , reply , len , 0)) < 0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    if (recv_size == 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
        return "";
    }
    printf("%i",recv_size);
    reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    return reply;
}





int ESocket::setAsNonBlock()
{

    int res;
    #ifdef _WIN32
    u_long iMode = 1;
    res = ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    #else
    int opts;
    opts = fcntl(s, F_GETFL);
    if(opts < 0)
    {
        res = -1;
    }
    opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fcntl(s, F_SETFL, opts) < 0)
    {
        res = -1;
    }
    #endif
    return res;
}



 -------------MAIN--------------

ESocket::Init();


EServer e(105);
while (e.isListening()){
ESocket x1("127.0.0.1",105);
printf("Connecting\n");
ESocket x2 = e.AcceptClient();
printf("Accepted\n");
x1.SendData("Ehem");
printf("Sent\n");
cout<<x2.ReceiveData(100);
printf("Received\n");
    Sleep(2000);
}
```

I will be happy if anyone can explain to me how can i solve it.

Comment: The `SOCKET` type is an alias for an integer value, and in C++ the macro `NULL` is often defined as `0` which actually is a valid socket number. `NULL` should be used for pointers only though, not for "clearing" integer values. Use `-1` if you want an illegal `SOCKET` value.

Comment: On windows, `SOCKET` is a pointer I think.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks i will keep it in my mind

Comment: @o11c [This MSDN reference on the socket data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740516(v=vs.85).aspx) says otherwise.

Comment: A slight addendum to my first comment: On Windows using winsock, `INVALID_SOCKET` should be used for an invalid socket.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes and it is about ~0 , what that means? i use < 0 for detecting invalid sockets , is it true?

Comment: @MHzCode `~0` in a normal [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) system happens to be equal to `-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a single global variable for all connected sockets. When you accept a socket that single socket will be assigned to the latest accepted socket. When a new socket connection is accepted you will overwrite the single variable with the new socket, losing the previous connection.

You should make these global variables private member variables in the class instead. By doing this the `SOCKET` variable will be unique for each instance of each `ESocket` instance.

---

There are also some stylistic things that could be improved. One I touched in my comment. Another is the variable names, `s` and `sx`? Not very descriptive, and I guess you chose `sx` because you could not use `s` in both source files? That should have been a sign of you doing something wrong.

---

And finally the most major flaw of them all: You're pulling the rug out under your own feet in the destructors.

The destructors call [`WSACleanup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741549(v=vs.85).aspx), which really cleans up the whole winsocket sub-system, and in the word of the linked [`WSACLeanup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741549(v=vs.85).aspx) reference:

> Sockets that were open when `WSACleanup` was called are reset and automatically deallocated as if `closesocket` were called.

This is very problematic because `EServer::AcceptClient` returns the newly created socket *by value* which causes a temporary instance to be created ***and destructed***. This destruction of the temporary object is what causes the whose socket sub-system to shut down. Any socket operation from that point onward will lead to errors.

You should call `WSACleanup` only once, when exiting the program.

If the destructor should do anything it should be to close the socket, but that will lead to other problems because you don't follow the [rule of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You definitely should follow the [rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) here, and implement a copy-constructor and copy-assignment operators.

Comment: Oh thanks man you saved my life! i will accept it in two minutes later.

Comment: yes i used it because i cannot use the same name in both source files and it was my wrong , im new in cpp.

Comment: But a problem is still persists.Now i can receive data but after a loop , server socket cannot accept connection and it will return INVALID_SOCKET in ESocket EServer::AcceptClient();

Comment: @MHzCode Continued to read your code, and found the actual reason for your problem. Answer updated.

Comment: Yes completely true , i should learn more about c++ before start programming with it :D

Comment: The actual fault is that i forgot to use Close(); in Destructor function , instead of Destruct(); , and also , the Destruct(); function shouldn't be defined in this class at all.I can define it as static in ESocket class and use it in the end of application.Another problem is that i defined SOCKET in cpp file globally and it should be defined in header file as private.And also i used 0 (NULL) as INVALID_SOCKET but it should be -1.